# ng-option failed to load json list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select ng-options="friends.data for friend in myFriends">
   <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

The object is a bit confusing, I tried many ways it just don't work.

the demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/Tz3d4dzXLxLn9XnhOqQx?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with select control you also need to add the ng-model, and since you work with collection you need to pass it as one `myFriends.friends.data`.

**Example:**

```
<select ng-model="friendsModel" ng-options="friend.name for friend in myFriends.friends.data">
        <option value="">Select friend</option>
 </select>
```

Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/BWjpYSfqCPFwtHrIvn1f?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You have written the `ng-options` wrongly and `ng-model` should be present.

Have a look into this code.

```
<select ng-model="frnd" ng-options="friend.name for friend in myFriends.friends.data">
```